# Parse.com and Logentries

Tags: parse-platform, loggly, logentries

I'm using Parse.com with iOS SDK. I really want to get all Parse logs into a third party service (Logentries) but I have no idea if Parse.com's logs can be exposed at all?

Obviously having log data which periodically gets deleted in Parse is not ideal, plus I can't filter it and an integration with Logentries could be amazing.

I'm referencing a previous unanswered question: [How to stream parse logs to a service provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287744/how-to-stream-parse-logs-to-a-service-provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logentries has a special endpoint for logging from AJAX and server-side JS applications. This means that for environments like Parse where using 3rd party libraries is awkward, direct integration is still dead simple- see [my fork](https://gist.github.com/m0wfo/759ce554750df5b136d2) of @Marco T's gist.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in pushing logs to Loggly using an edited version of: https://gist.github.com/rogernolan/95ea615164e343b3bc54

Comment: It allows me to use logger.log('') but I have to manually log things.

Comment: The Parse.com log includes things outside of console.log that won't export

Comment: Yes, logs are not automatic. At a response.error or response.success, you must call logger.log('');.